# How to add foreign key in Laravel 5.1 Integrity constraint violation: 1452?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am adding a foreign key to **Tickets** Table. The other table is **ticket_statuses**.

In artisan, i executed this command: **php artisan make:migration add_ticket_status_to_tickets_table**

This is the code inside the migration file:

```
      class AddTicketStatusToTicketsTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {

            Schema::table('tickets', function ($table) {
                $table->integer('ticket_status_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('ticket_status_id')->references('id')->on('ticket_statuses')->onDelete('cascade');
            });

        }
     }
```

After that, i try to implement a relationship. This is my code inside **Tickets Model**:

```
class Ticket extends Model
{

    // Ticket __belongs_to__ Ticket Status
    public function ticket_status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TicketStatus');
    }
}
```

In artisan, i executed **php artisan migrate** But I **encountered an error**

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`idealcrmalphadb`.`#sql-4ea_1ce`, CONSTRAINT `tickets_ticket_status_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`ticket_status_id`) REFERENCES `tickets` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: alter table `tickets` add constraint tickets_ticket_status_id_foreign foreignkey (`ticket_status_id`) references `tickets` (`id`) on delete cascade)

 [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`idealcrmalphadb`.`#sql-4ea_1ce`, CONSTRAINT `tickets_ticket_status_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`ticket_status_id`) REFERENCES `tickets` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Have i made mistake in the model part? Please help

Comment: Are you sure it's `on('tickets')`? You probably have another table for ticket statuses. Something like `ticket_statuses`. If that's the case then, chage `on('tickets')` to `on('ticket_statuses')` or to whatever the name of your ticket statuses table is.

Comment: Hi @Doom5 . I have a ticket_statuses table. $table->foreign('ticket_status_id')->references('id')->on('ticket_statuses')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your migration table name and reference table name. You have mistake here.

UPD:

It looks like you already have data in tickets table. If so, you can try now

```
$table->integer('ticket_status_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Comment: I already checked migration and reference table name. It looks correct.

Comment: It looks like you already have data in `tickets` table. If so, you can try now

`$table->integer('ticket_status_id')->unsigned()->nullable();`